# ASP.NET MVC5 Accessint HttpContext.Current.Request in ValidationAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-5, request, httpcontext

Is there any way to access HttpContext.Current.Request in ValidationAttribute?

I have code like this:

```
public class RequiredLAttribute : RequiredAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public RequiredLAttribute()
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Get("test");
    }


    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

So, I want to make my own version of Required ValidationAttribute and i have to use cookie to check something and then do rest of the operations.

Every time i want to access this property throws exception:

> System.Web.HttpException: The request is not available in this context

Thanks for help.

Comment: was there any solution for this?